# ERROR ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred (oracle forms 11g)

Tags: forms, oracle, ora-12170

I'm struggling to connect to the database using oracle forms 11g. I'm using my machine as a local host using weblogic and XE database. When I try to connect to the database using oracle forms, this error pops

> "ERROR ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred"

Here are the files
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN

**listener**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NB**MyIP**.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

---

**sqlnet**

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

---

**tnsnames**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NB**MyIP**.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

I also changed

```
HOST = NB**MyIP**.com)(PORT = 1521)) to
HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

and copied all files to C:\Oracle\Middleware10_3\asinst_1

and copied tnsnames to
C:\Oracle\Middleware10_3\asinst_1\config

I have another C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home for JDeveloper.

I don't have technical experience to solve it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z49E1.jpg

Comment: Can you connect using SQLPlus? Did you check sqlnet.log?

Comment: yes i'm connecting using (SQL command line) and it connects.

Comment: I don't have sql*plus

Comment: I just found sqlplus telling me when I connect 

"ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error "

I checked the services and all running

Answer (score 0):

try changing sqlnet.ora

add: NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES)

and comment out: #SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)

copy sqlnet.ora to the asinst_1/config directory

Answer (score 0):

if your oracle database installed on Windows server, then pls check your windows server firewall setting , make sure you shut down windows inner firewall